# Setup usb-ethernet usb3.0 adapters on ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, usb

I have the following attached to my ubuntu server:

1x Usb 3.0 hub
4x Usb/Rj45 adapters (that also have usb ports), and to one of them a WD hard disk.

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubnt 5.0.0-050000-generic #201903032031 SMP Mon Mar 4 01:33:18 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 010: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 004 Device 008: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc.
Bus 004 Device 009: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc.
Bus 004 Device 007: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc.
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 05e3:0612 Genesys Logic, Inc.
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc.
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 0557:2419 ATEN International Co., Ltd
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0557:7000 ATEN International Co., Ltd Hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 1058:1021 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements Desktop (WDBAAU)
Bus 003 Device 011: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 09eb:0131 IM Networks, Inc.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am trying to get my 4 rj45 adapters to be recognised. Currently ifconfig doesn't find anything and i am struggling finding anything that can make them work.

-- Edit

```
sudo modprobe r8152 && dmesg | grep r8152
[   40.359976] r8152 4-2.1.4:1.0 eth0: v1.09.9
[   40.460149] r8152 4-2.2.4:1.0 eth1: v1.09.9
[   40.564252] r8152 4-2.4.4:1.0 eth2: v1.09.9
[   40.711722] r8152 4-2.3.4:1.0 eth3: v1.09.9
[   40.711820] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[   40.727129] r8152 4-2.4.4:1.0 enx00e04c6802c0: renamed from eth2
[   40.759099] r8152 4-2.2.4:1.0 enx00e04c6802cc: renamed from eth1
[   40.799284] r8152 4-2.1.4:1.0 enx00e04c68024d: renamed from eth0
[   40.823044] r8152 4-2.3.4:1.0 enx00e04c6802cd: renamed from eth3
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8152 && dmesg | grep r8152`

Comment: Added @chili555

Comment: May I assume that they now appear in `ifconfig`? Please attach a known good ethernet cable and do: `sudo dhclient -v` Does one of them connect? Which? Or are there other alarming messages?